# Maven - correct version of a plugin found in an alternate repository instead of Maven central: how to force it?

Tags: maven

I’m trying to get org.jfrog.buildinfo:artifactory-maven-plugin:2.6.1 which can be found in https://jcenter.bintray.com.

But since there is a 2.2.1 version of the same artifact in Maven Central, resolve always fails

```
« Failure to find org.jfrog.buildinfo:artifactory-maven-plugin:jar:2.6.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 »
```

I tried reordering the repositories section in pom.xml, no luck.

Any clue?

Thanks.

Edit: I was looking for a plugin !

Comment: please add your pom.xml <repositories>

Comment: also the plugins section

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I was looking for a plugin, not a dependency.

Answer (score 5):

Got it !

I was using `repositories` instead of `pluginRepositories`

This:

```
<repositories>
  <!-- not! -->
  <repository>
    <id>jcenter</id>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </repository>
  <!-- -->
</repositories>
```

Instead of this:

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <!-- yes! -->
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>jcenter</id>
    <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Of course, as I was trying to get a plugin, I should have been using `pluginRepository`.

Answer (score 1):

1. download the `artifactory-maven-plugin` (jar and `pom.xml`) to your local disk.
2. install the jar to your local repository:

   `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path_to_downloaded_jar>
        -DpomFile=<path_to_downloaded_pom>`

Comment: I know I can do something like that, but it means I have to do it on all developers' computers, and CI too…

Comment: To avoid this (and for other reasons), it's helpful to use a Repository Manager in your LAN/Intranet, like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) or [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks @JimHawkins , I took your advice and installed artifactory to centralize repositories settings, and add in house dependencies.